# Mixed Model t Test (Toothaker’s t-Test)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mixed-model, spss, excel

I'm trying to do a follow up test for a mixed model ANOVA, and I figured that I need do a Mixed Model t test also known as Toothaker's test. I just don't know how do it. I was wondering if anyone has an Excel sheet that can calculate this for me, because I know SPSS can't.

I'm doing a mixed model ANOVA and I found significant interactions between my within subjects variables and my between subjects variables. Notes from a previous year's stats course told me to use a mixed model t-test to examine these interactions, and we were given an Excel sheet to help us calculate it. However I lost this Excel sheet.

To clarify more I have two between subject conditions (drug/placebo) and two within subject conditions (memory tested at 2 different times).

In my notes the test is called Toothaker's Mixed Model t-test and is described as such "Used when 1 (or more) within-subjects factor and 1 (or more) between subjects factor: Toothaker’s mixed-model t test (pools MS error)"

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-design_analysis_of_variance#Follow-up_tests) seems to describe a similar thing "when there is a significant interaction between a between-subject factor and a within-subject factor, statisticians often recommended pooling the between-subject and within-subject MSerror terms.[2][page needed][citation needed] This can be calculated in the following way:
MSWCELL = SSBSError + SSWSError / dfBSError + dfWSError"

Comment: Can you clarify this? I don't follow how the first sentence is a question. What is the "tooth takers test"? Can you say a little more about your situation, your data &  your goals? Is this just repeated measures ANOVA, but w/ only 2 groups?

Comment: I made some edits to my initial question, hopefully it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I'm confused on too, in my notes from last year its called the "Toothtakers Mixed Model ANOVA" but I really did not get much information from google. Maybe it's not a standard test? But in the case I described what test would you use to examine the interactions?

Comment: Some quick Googling established that this test is due to Larry E. Toothaker, so it would be described as "Toothaker's test" (no "the" in front). Your varying use of lower and upper case and some inconsistency in spelling as well was a little confusing.